# The best way to learn Ajax

Tags: ajax

My question is simple, which is the most logical way to learn to handle the concepts of ajax, and that time should be spent on each phase of this new model.

Comment: *that time should be spent on each phase of this new model* uh?

Comment: I mean how long on average should be used to dominate in a basic ajax

Comment: The answer to this question is: *"As long as it takes"*.

Comment: This is not a real question, "AJAX" may be changed to another term without making any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest thing of learning something, is doing something.

First of all, you need to understand the fundametals.. what is AJAX, what was before AJAX and what exact issues does it solve.

After you might consider to learn jQuery AJAX API (http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for client side and PHP (or any other language, that is easy to start) as server. And do some small tasks - as one of AJAX kata, it could be implementation of 'Google word suggest'.

Comment: Thanks friend Alexander excellent recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

Given you have some web development experience, I suggest the following book - it is really excellent in my opinion:

[http://www.amazon.com/Ajax-Definitive-Anthony-Holdener-III/dp/0596528388/ref=pd_sim_b_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528388)